# Laravel clear cache getting new error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just cleared the cache for my project because my html wasn't updating and now I get and error something went wrong and it displays twice and I don't no what the error is how do I fix this could someone help me out please

Comment: You could check your logs for why `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 0):

at first

- write access bootstrap and storage folder .
- composer dump-autoload
- run php artisan clear cache

then your problem will be solve

Comment: what do you mean write access bootstrap and storage folder .

Comment: sometimes it can not write error information this folder